# Check if string contains a word

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, string, replace

```
Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

string rt = "tst xtstx xtste tst tst!!";

if (rnd.Next(3) == 0)
{
    string[] replaceWords = { "something", "nice" };
    rt.Replace("tst", replaceWords[rnd.Next(replaceWords.Length - 1)]);
}
if (rnd.Next(3) == 0)
{
    string[] replaceWords = { "cool", "crazy" };
    rt.Replace("xtste", replaceWords[rnd.Next(replaceWords.Length - 1)]);
}
```

I want to replace a word with a random one from a array with a 33% chance. The problem is if I run this it will replace all occurrences of tst, and only to replace this occurrences:

```
string rt = "tst xtstx xtste tst tst!!";
//           /\              /\  /\
```

There is a better way to do this only replacing the words ? 
I will use the same idea multiple times in my code.

Comment: @crush replce("\btst\b") ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on exactly what you want to do I think...can you clarify your question any better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use regular expressions for this.

Regex that match all `tst` words, you need to use `\btst\b` regex.

To replace all occurances use one of [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.

[Here is a something similar example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also don't use `Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)`, default constructor of `Random` has better seed than this.

Example:

```
static Random rnd = new Random();
static string Replace(string input, string word, params string[] words)
{
     return Regex.Replace(input, "\b" + word + "\b", m=>words[rnd.Next(words.Length)]);
}
```

now you can use it as this:

```
string rt = "tst xtstx xtste tst tst!!";

if (rnd.Next(3) == 0)
{
    rt = Replace(rt, "tst", "something", "nice");
}
if (rnd.Next(3) == 0)
{
    rt = Replace(rt, "xtste", "cool", "crazy");
}
```

Comment: There is a clean way to do this ? since i am goin to reproduce the same idea multiple times ?

Comment: I will need multiple if with Radom rnd this 2 lines ?

Comment: Why using m=>words[rnd.Next(words.Length)] insted of words[rnd.Next(words.Length)]?

Comment: when you use `words[rnd.Next(words.Length)]` you pass one selected word and it replaces all found words with this word. But when you pass `m=>words[rnd.Next(words.Length)]`, you pass a function, that will be called for each found match to select replacement, so each replacement will be randomized.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44728/discussion-between-gorfi-and-oleh-nechytailo)

Answer (score 1):

Do this.  Use `Regex.Replace` and `/b` to use only the word.

```
Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

string rt = "tst xtstx xtste tst tst!!";

if (rnd.Next(3) == 0)
{
    string[] replaceWords = { "something", "nice" };
    rt = Regex.Replace(rt, @"\tst\b", replaceWords[rnd.Next(replaceWords.Length - 1)]);
}
if (rnd.Next(3) == 0)
{
    string[] replaceWords = { "cool", "crazy" };
    rt = Regex.Replace(rt, @"\xtste\b", replaceWords[rnd.Next(replaceWords.Length - 1)]);
}
```

method to do some of the repeated work.

```
public string ReplaceRandom(string[] words, string wordToReplace, string inputString)
{
    Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\b" + wordToReplace + @"\b", words[rnd.Next(words.Length - 1)]);
    return inputString;
}
```

Or if you wanted to use an extension method to kind of stick with the `String.Replace` line of thinking you could do.  Call it with `rt.ReplaceWithRandom(replaceWords, "tst");`

```
public static string ReplaceWithRandom(this string inputString, string[] words, string wordToReplace)
{
    Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\b" + wordToReplace + @"\b", words[rnd.Next(words.Length - 1)]);
}
```

Comment: Since i am goin to use this code multiple times there is a way to make it cleaner ?

Comment: @Gorfi are you wanting to pull this functionality out into a separate function or just make the code shorter?

Comment: Just make easy to implement a new wordToReplace with replaceWords array.

Comment: @Gorfi I added a function, see if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Why usign x => words[rnd.Next(words.Length)]) instead of words[rnd.Next(words.Length)])

Comment: @Gorfi I edited it to match what you were doing before.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `\b` to denote a word boundry with a regular expression.

Also - don't forget to assign back to the original string!

```
Random rnd = new Random();

string rt = "tst xtstx xtste tst tst!!";

if (rnd.Next(3) == 0)
{
    string[] replaceWords = { "something", "nice" };
    rt = Regex.Replace(rt, @"\btst\b", replaceWords[rnd.Next(replaceWords.Length - 1)]);
}
if (rnd.Next(3) == 0)
{
    string[] replaceWords = { "cool", "crazy" };
    rt = Regex.Replace(rt, @"\bxtste\b", replaceWords[rnd.Next(replaceWords.Length - 1)]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you want a different random word for each match. Here's a class that will do this for you.

```
public class RandomStringReplacer
{
    // no need to seed this w/ the current time, the default constructor does that already
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();

    private readonly Regex _regex;

    private readonly string[] _replacementStrings;

    public RandomStringReplacer(string pattern, params string[] replacementStrings)
    {
        _regex = new Regex(pattern);
        _replacementStrings = replacementStrings.ToArray();
    }

    // each time we get a replacement string, a randomly selected one is chosen
    private string RandomReplacement
    {
        get { return _replacementStrings[_random.Next(_replacementStrings.Length)]; }
    }

    public string Replace(string text)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var result = text;

        // get the matches as a stack, because we want to replace backwards so that indexes still match the correct spot in the string
        var matches = new Stack<Match>(_regex.Matches(text).OfType<Match>());
        while (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            var match = matches.Pop();
            // each match has a 1/3 chance to be replaced
            if (random.Next(3) == 0)
            {
                result = result.Remove(match.Index, match.Length).Insert(match.Index, RandomReplacement);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var replacements = new[]{"foo", "bar", "FUBAR"};
var pattern = @"(tst)|(xtste)";
var replacer = new RandomStringReplacer(pattern, replacements);

var text = "tst xtstx xtste tst tst!!";
replacer.Replace(text).Dump();
```